# Iframe URL - PHP or Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, url, iframe

I'm trying to build a custom top toolbar which an iframe below it.

Something similar to this:
http://themes.goodlayers.com/?theme=greenearth

I plan one using it on a blog, so i will be making posts linking to other sites. My question is what do i need to make a custom url function that so i just add it in front of the other site's url so that it shows up in an iframe.

For example:

I want to link to google in an iframe with my top toolbar above.

Is there a script that allows me to use a url like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/frame.php?http://www.google.com/

Thanks for your time!

Comment: dont use iframes, bad practices almost always. and google will stop you iframing it.

Comment: @Dagon, Seems like a good use case to me...

Comment: perhaps, but you can't iframe google it sends the X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header.

Answer (score 0):

Iframes are always bad. Don't do it.

That said, with PHP, you can do this:

```
<iframe src="<? echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?>" />
```

You can also do something like mywebsite.com?url=google.com, and use $_GET['url'] instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Eg url: http://mywebsite.com/index.php?iframe=http://www.google.ro
2. PHP:

   ```
   <?php

     if ($_GET['iframe']) {

     echo"<iframe src='".$_GET['iframe']"' width='200px' height='150px'>";

   } ?>
   ```

I hope this will help you!